# kivyファイルをpyinstallerでexe化したけど起動したら真っ黒な画面のウィンドウが出る

Tags: python, windows-10, pyinstaller, kivy

windows10を使っており、kivyを用いて電卓のアプリを作り、これをexe化するためにpyinstallerを用いました。しかし、exe化はできたのですが、そのexeファイルを起動すると真っ黒な画面のウィンドウが出てきて、電卓の画面が表示されません。コマンドプロンプトからpythonファイルを直接実行すると、きちんと電卓の画面が出てきます。また、pyinstallerでのexe化については以下のサイトを参考にしました。

[Python KivyのGUIアプリをExe化する方法](https://torimakujoukyou.com/python-kivy-exe/)

以下にspecファイルのコードを示します。

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['calculator.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    name='calculator',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)

coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('.'),
            a.binaries,
            a.zipfiles,
            a.datas,
            *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
            strip=False,
            upx=True,
            name='calculator')
```

やはり上記のサイトにある通り、うまく起動しないことがあるものだとあきらめざるを得ないのでしょうか？
どなたかこのことについてご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 色んな原因でエラーが発生するようですね。[【Python】Pythonファイルを実行ファイルに変換する方法【exe化】](https://yumarublog.com/python/exe/) の最後の方の「エラーが発生した時の対処法」の所をみて色々と調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: あるいは単にspecファイルに`console=True`が指定されているから？ そもそものアプリケーションのスクリプトはどんな機能と見え方を持ったプログラムなのでしょうか？ それが単なる「表示されません」や「画面が出てきます」と書かれているだけでは問題を再現したり原因を調査するのは難しいでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に、ソースコード(参考にした記事そのままというならそこへのリンク)やPyInstallerへ指示するコマンドの詳細等も提示してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 「pyinstaller ファイル名 --noconsole」というように「--noconsole」をビルドするときにつけてみてビルドしたらどうなりますか？背景が黒ということなのでコマンドプロンプト画面が表示されているのか疑うのことになるかと思います。その黒い画面でクリックしてみて白く点滅するならおそらくコマンドプロンプト画面かと思います。